# Simplification of conjugate expression with integers

Tags: complex

I have a long expression that contains $(-1)^q$, where $q$ is an integer. I'm taking conjugate of this expression, and Mathematica gives me the term Conjugate[(-1)^q]. And, of course, I'd like to get $(-1)^q$.

For the sake of simplicity, I tried to run the following command:

`Assuming[Element[q, Integers], Conjugate[(-1)^q]]`

And the result was

`Conjugate[(-1)^q]`

I also tried Simplify and FullSimplify commands; however, the result remained the same.

Comment: `Table[-1^q,{q,-3,3}]` seems to show that -1^q is -1 for any finite integer q. Even `Simplify[-1^q,Element[q,Integers]]` knows this is true. So why don't you do that or even do `yourexpression/.(-1)^q->-1` or something similar and be get on with the rest of the work you need to do?

Comment: That is a great idea! Thank you!

Comment: `ComplexExpand` is also useful in this case, `Simplify[ComplexExpand[Conjugate[(-1)^q]], Element[q, Integers]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 3 ways to get the result you seek (perhaps you were not using the correct syntax)

```
Assuming[Element[q, Integers], Refine[Conjugate[(-1)^q]]]
(* (-1)^q *)

Assuming[Element[q, Integers], Simplify[Conjugate[(-1)^q]]]
(* (-1)^q *)

Assuming[Element[q, Integers], FullSimplify[Conjugate[(-1)^q]]]
(* (-1)^q *)
```

Note that `Refine` is a more specialist version of `Simplify`, just applying the assumption.

Comment: Thank you very much!